# Email nested if statement AMPScript with HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, conditional

I need to have a nested if statement with some HTML inside.

Like this.

```
%%[ IF (NOT EMPTY(@Var1) THEN ]%%
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
        %%[ IF (NOT EMPTY(@Var2) THEN
        <!-- HTML goes here -->
        %%[ ENDIF ]%%
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

But if I try to set it like this I'm getting an error that the first IF statement is never closed and the code doesen't work.

What am I doing wrong? I was under the impression that AmpScript has the option to use nested if statements. Is it a syntax error or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not closing a `%%[` on line number 4. You are missing two `)` on line 1 and 3 too.

Try this:

```
%%[ IF (NOT EMPTY(@Var1)) THEN ]%%
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
        %%[ IF (NOT EMPTY(@Var2)) THEN ]%%
        <!-- HTML goes here -->
        %%[ ENDIF ]%%
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied it in a rush from the project and simplifying the code I missed some stuff. I checked the project and it is like in your example so I edited the question to fix the problem. The error message is still there, sadly.

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly like my example? I've just tested it in Content Builder and it's working fine. Can you post your full code? Maybe something is missing elsewhere ...

Comment: It was actually one of the opening parentheses missing, I rolled back the question to the original state for clarity. Thank you.